# Hide Mouse Pointer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5

I am attempting to hide the mouse pointer when there has been a few seconds of inactivity and then re-show the pointer again when the user moves the mouse.  I have been able to get the mouse pointer to hide and re-show as I require it, however when I execute `grid.Children.Clear()` and `grid.Children.Add()` the mouse pointer re-appears (but again hides after a few seconds of inactivity).

My code is as below:

```
Private Sub Window1_MouseMoved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
  'MsgBox("Mouse Has Moved", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Mouse Moved")
  LastMouseMove = DateTime.Now
  If IsHidden Then
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    IsHidden = False
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseHide_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Dim elaped As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - LastMouseMove
  If elaped >= TimeoutToHide AndAlso Not IsHidden Then
    Cursor = Cursors.None
    IsHidden = True
    'System.Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub setupMouseHide()
  Try
    'Dim timer As New System.Timers.Timer(1000)
    Dim dispatcherTimer As DispatcherTimer = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
    AddHandler dispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf MouseHide_Tick
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 3)
    dispatcherTimer.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Setup Display Message: error encountered")
  End Try
End Sub
```

I was wondering if this is a known issue or is there a better way of achieving what I am seeking to do?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug, but its not uncommon for layout changes to cause a mouse move event to be raised.

I'd say your best bet might be to check and store the actual coordinates of the mouse in that mouse move event. That way you can ignore the errant mouse move events.

Not ideal, but I think it would work.